# tabulator question - Why is it requested multiple times when using ajax?

Tags: tabulator

```
ajaxLoader:true,
ajaxFiltering:true,
ajaxProgressiveLoad:"scroll",
ajaxProgressiveLoadDelay:200,
ajaxConfig:"POST",
ajaxProgressiveLoadScrollMargin : 10,
```

I used the above settings and worked in the order below.

```
clearFilter();
addFilter()
setData()
```

At this time, 3 requests occur.

One request with no filter applied.
The filter applied has been requested twice.

What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

That is correct operation of the table. You have Ajax filtering enabled in your settings.

- When you clear the filters a request must be made to retrieve the unfiltered data.
- Then when you add a filter it must request the filtered data.
- Then when you change the data URL with set data it makes another request.

If all you want to do is set a filter then there is no need to call `clearFilter` then `addFilter` then `setData`, you can simply call `setFilter` which will do all of the above in one action with one request.

```js
table.setFilter("age", "=”, 12);
```

You only need to call the `setData` function in this instance if you want to change the base url of the request.

An explanation of this can be found in the first section of the [Filter Documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.9/filter#overview)

Comment: At first, I wanted to send only one filter request with the data not being loaded.
What order should we go through to perform this action?